# Integré la fuente RSS de SOes pero tiene demasiada actividad ¿cómo la filtro?

Tags: soporte

Agregué a un canal de Slack la fuente de RSS de SOes pero tiene demasiada actividad. ¿Cómo la filtro?

Answer (score 3):

## Resumen

Para recibir menos notificaciones, en lugar de usar la fuente del canal de preguntas del sitio, usa una fuente con menos actividad, como lo puede ser la fuente de una etiqueta, de las preguntas interesantes, tus etiquetas favoritas, o un filtro personalizado.

## Instrucciones

### Obtener el enlace a la fuente RSS de una etiqueta

De [¿Cómo encuentro los temas en los que estoy interesado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)

> Si quieres recibir notificaciones de nueva actividad de cierta etiqueta, puedes suscribirte para recibir correo electrónico o RSS ubicando el mouse sobre la etiqueta, esperar un momento a que aparezcan las opciones y seleccionado el método que prefieras.
>
> [image: Suscríbete vía email o rss]

Nota: Lo anterior funciona en algunos lugares donde se muestran las etiquetas, no en todos. Por ejemplo, funciona en las etiquetas debajo de cada pregunta en [página de preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions) y en la [página de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags) del sitio, pero no en la etiquetas que se muestran en Etiquetas Favoritas ni en las Etiquetas Relacionadas, las cuales son secciones que se muestran en el panel derecho de algunas páginas.

### Crear un filtro personalizado

1. Ve a http://stackexchange.com
2. Si no lo has hecho aún, inicia sesión.
3. Haz clic en [Filtered Questions](http://stackexchange.com/filters)
4. Configura y guardo tu filtro
5. Ve a la página de tu filtro, al pie de la lista de preguntas el enlace a la fuente RSS, cópialo y agrégalo a tu herramienta.

**Véase también:**

De meta.se

- [RSS feed of your favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags?rq=1)
- [RSS feed for responses to your posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/rss-feed-for-responses-to-your-posts)
- [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its)

Comment: O sea que no puedo filtrar la fuente a la que me suscribí, sino suscribirme a otra... Creo que no se responde a la pregunta. Por ejemplo, me suscribo a la fuente del sitio y **la única tag** que no quiero ver es `java`. **¿Puedo filtrar la fuente RSS _y no ver_ la tag `java`?** La alternativa sería suscribirme a todas las tags, menos a java.

Comment: Edité la respuesta. ¿Mejor?